# "Error: inherits(obj, "Spatial") is not TRUE"

Tags: raster, r-raster

I would like to create contour lines (50%, 75%, 95%) from following raster object (r1) which can be transferred to ArcGIS. But I always getting error message: "Error: inherits(obj, "Spatial") is not TRUE".

```
contour1 <- contour(r1, levels=c(.5, .75, .95), add=TRUE)
library(rgdal)
writeOGR(contour1, ".", paste("r1"), driver="ESRI Shapefile")
################ 


class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 703, 524, 368372  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 10000, 10000  (x, y)
extent      : -2839438, 2400562, -3450852, 3579148  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=aeqd +ellps=WGS84 +lon_0=89.5525 +lat_0=43.234 
data source : in memory
names       : layer 
values      : 1e-07, 2.888137  (min, max)
```

Comment: what do you mean by "which can be transferred to ArcGIS", and which command exactly gave you the error message?

Comment: Thanks you Edzer, I wold like to create shape file by writeOGR command but "writeOGR(contour1, ".", paste("r1"), driver="ESRI Shapefile")" gave the error message; I understand that contour1 is not "spatial" ; may be due to this; is there anyway to create contour on raster file.

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
library(sp)
library(maptools)
l = quantile(r1[], c(.05, .5, .95))
sl = ContourLines2SLDF(contourLines(as.image.SpatialGridDataFrame(as(r1, "SpatialGridDataFrame")), levels = l))
library(rgdal)
writeOGR(sl, ".", paste("r1"), driver="ESRI Shapefile")
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It work but creates arbitrarily contour lines. If I would like to create control lines at particular level such as 50%, 75% and 99% from the raster file (values range 1e-07, 2.888137). If I add, levels=c(.50, .75, .99) onto your code then seems it does not give any contour as I presume my values range 1e-07, 2.888137  (min, max)); sl = ContourLines2SLDF(contourLines(as.image.SpatialGridDataFrame(as(r1, "SpatialGridDataFrame"), levels=c(.50, .75, .999))), would be great help, if you kindly provide me clue to do 50%, 75% and 100% contour

Comment: ah, I see; I added the quantile command to get some quantiles (in this case, .05, .50 and .95 quantiles) to the example above. Hth,

Comment: Last two weeks, I was trying to find out how I can turn these contours into filled contour plot. I looked at filled.contours, raster2contour..but no luck; could you please provide some clues.regards..Lutfor

Comment: try not to think filling contours but colouring grid cells; use `plot`, `image` or `spplot`.